# index out of range when generating a csv

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I am trying to build a sports betting program.

Right now I am stuck at the part where it is generating a csv with all of the box scores for the previous two college basketball seasons. It is pulling the boxscore indexes from the csv I have already generated.

I keep getting index out of range error once it hits 10653 iterations on the progress bar. I can't find anything specific in the csv it is reading at the 10653rd row.

I know the iterations correspond to rows in the csv because when I run all line of code prior to `df = Boxscore(box_link).dataframe` the progress bar completes at 14980 iterations, which is the same number of rows in the csv it is reading.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The code is below along with the error message.

```py
from sportsreference.ncaab.boxscore import Boxscore
start_season = 2020 # below code will pull data from all seasons starting from this year
box_df = None
schedule_df = pd.read_csv('ncaab - sheet81 - ncaab - sheet81.csv')#if only running for testing, a smaller csv may be used to speed up the process
season_df = schedule_df.loc[schedule_df.Season>=start_season]
for index, row in tqdm(season_df.iterrows()):
    box_link = row['BoxscoreIndex']
    _df = Boxscore(box_link).dataframe #The line to left is where the error keeps coming in "list index out of range". I ran everything above this and it works fine.  
        
    if box_df is not None:
        box_df = pd.concat([box_df,_df],axis=0)
    else:
        box_df = _df
            
box_df.to_csv('boxscores3.csv'.format(start_season),index=None)
```

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-91c5b71b03e2> in <module>
      6 for index, row in tqdm(season_df.iterrows()):
      7     box_link = row['BoxscoreIndex']
----> 8     _df = Boxscore(box_link).dataframe #The line to left is where the error keeps coming in "list index out of range". I ran everything above this and it works fine.
      9 
     10     if box_df is not None:

~\Downloads\WPy64-3860\python-3.8.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\sportsreference\ncaab\boxscore.py in __init__(self, uri)
    223         self._home_defensive_rating = None
    224 
--> 225         self._parse_game_data(uri)
    226 
    227     def _retrieve_html_page(self, uri):

~\Downloads\WPy64-3860\python-3.8.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\sportsreference\ncaab\boxscore.py in _parse_game_data(self, uri)
    668             if short_field == 'away_record' or \
    669                short_field == 'home_record':
--> 670                 value = self._parse_record(short_field, boxscore, index)
    671                 setattr(self, field, value)
    672                 continue

~\Downloads\WPy64-3860\python-3.8.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\sportsreference\ncaab\boxscore.py in _parse_record(self, field, boxscore, index)
    375         records = boxscore(BOXSCORE_SCHEME[field]).items()
    376         records = [x.text() for x in records if x.text() != '']
--> 377         return records[index]
    378 
    379     def _find_boxscore_tables(self, boxscore):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: where does the import sportsreference.ncaab.boxscore come from?

Comment: Earlier in the code I install the sports reference module through pip install sportsrefernce

Comment: That is also what I used earlier to generate the csv with all of the box score indexes. That part works fine, but then when I attempt to use those indexes to generate a csv with the full box scores I get the index out of range error.  The weird part is that I first attempted this with a much smaller csv where I deleted most of the rows in the csv that it was reading and it worked fine. However I am trying to use as much data as possible because I am using this data in a LGBM model to determine feature importances.

Comment: share atleast the first few rows (maybe 5) of 'ncaab - sheet81 - ncaab - sheet81.csv'

Comment: also include row 10653, since thats where the issue is

Comment: my guess is that on row 10653, there is no table to parse or something different with that particular boxscore. But can't know for sure unless you share that part of the schedule csv file.

Comment: Feel free to look through whatever you need to in the csv.  I am currently attempting to run the code with row 10653 and a few rows on either side removed.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FNEW06wFdr8d_RqERjxnN-DaKp3GIzxID6wu7z4Djik/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: which table are you after? The basic or advanced?

Comment: few things I'm noticing, you don't need to go to each url twice. Just go once, and get both tables. Second, looks like that line is fine. My guess is that the site is blocking you (over 10,000 requests is an weful lot. And it does say in their ToS to not automate in such a way that overloads their servers.) I'll help you work out a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

first, just want to point out that the .format() method `'boxscores3.csv'.format(start_season)` here doesnt do anything. it's still going to return `'boxscores3.csv'`. You'd need to have that placeholder within the string to have that in the filename:

so for example if `start_season = '2020'`, then `'boxscores3_{0}.csv'.format(start_season)` would give you `'boxscores3_2020.csv'`

So if you want that filename dynamic, change to:

`box_df.to_csv('boxscores3_{0}.csv'.format(start_season),index=None)`

or

`box_df.to_csv('boxscores3_{some_variable}.csv'.format(some_variable = start_season),index=None)`

or

`box_df.to_csv('boxscores3_%s.csv' %start_season),index=None)`

Next, until you can provide a sample of that csv file, specifically row 10653, can't really help you with the specific issue.

However, until then, I can offer an alternate solution using espn api.

You can get box scores of college basketball games, provided you have the gameId. So this code will go through each date (need to give a start date), get the gameIds of each game. Then with the gameIds, can go get the boxscore from another api endpoint. Unfortunetly, the boxscore isn't returned in a json format, but rather the html (which is fine because we can use `pandas` to read in the table).

I don't know exactly what you need or want, but this may help you while you are learning python to see other ways to get data:

**Code:**

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime


date_list = []
sdate = datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)   # start date
edate = datetime.date.today()  # end date

delta = edate - sdate       # as timedelta

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = sdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    date_list.append(day.strftime("%Y%m%d"))

 


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'xhr': '1',
'device': 'desktop',
'country': 'us',
'lang': 'en',
'region': 'us',
'site': 'espn',
'edition-host': 'espn.com',
'site-type': 'full'}

# Get gameIds
gameId_dict = {}
for dateStr in tqdm(date_list):
    url = 'https://secure.espn.com/core/mens-college-basketball/schedule/_/date/{dateStr}/group/50'.format(dateStr=dateStr)
    games = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()['content']['schedule'][dateStr]['games']
    gameId_dict[dateStr] = []
    for game in games:
        # Check if game was postponed
        if game['status']['type']['name'] in ['STATUS_POSTPONED','STATUS_CANCELED','STATUS_SCHEDULED']:
            continue
        game_info = {}
        game_info[game['id']] = {}
        game_info[game['id']]['awayTeam'] = game['shortName'].split('@')[0].strip()
        game_info[game['id']]['homeTeam'] = game['shortName'].split('@')[1].strip()
        gameId_dict[dateStr].append(game_info)



full_df = pd.DataFrame()
# Box score - gameId needed
box_url = 'https://secure.espn.com/core/mens-college-basketball/boxscore'
for dateStr, games in tqdm(gameId_dict.items()):
    for game in tqdm(games):
        for gameId, teams in game.items():
            payload = {
            'gameId': gameId,
            'xhr': '1',
             'render': 'true',
            'device': 'desktop',
            'country': 'us',
            'lang': 'en',
            'region': 'us',
            'site': 'espn',
            'edition-host': 'espn.com',
            'site-type': 'full'}
            
            data = requests.get(box_url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
            away_df = pd.read_html(data['content']['html'], header=1)[0].rename(columns={'Bench':'Player'})
            away_df = away_df[away_df['Player'] != 'TEAM']
            away_df = away_df[away_df['Player'].notna()]
            away_df['Team'] = teams['awayTeam']
            away_df['Home_Away'] = 'Away'
            away_df['Starter_Bench'] = 'Bench'
            away_df.loc[0:4, 'Starter_Bench'] = 'Starter'
            away_df['Player'] = away_df['Player'].str.split(r"([a-z]+)([A-Z].+)", expand=True)[2]
            away_df[['Player','Team']] = away_df['Player'].str.extract('^(.*?)([A-Z]+)$', expand=True)
                    
            home_df = pd.read_html(data['content']['html'], header=1)[1].rename(columns={'Bench':'Player'})
            home_df = home_df[home_df['Player'] != 'TEAM']
            home_df = home_df[home_df['Player'].notna()]
            home_df['Team'] = teams['homeTeam']
            home_df['Home_Away'] = 'Home'
            home_df['Starter_Bench'] = 'Bench'
            home_df.loc[0:4, 'Starter_Bench'] = 'Starter'
            home_df['Player'] = home_df['Player'].str.split(r"([a-z]+)([A-Z].+)", expand=True)[2]
            home_df[['Player','Team']] = home_df['Player'].str.extract('^(.*?)([A-Z]+)$', expand=True)
            
            game_df = away_df.append(home_df, sort = False)
            game_df['Date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
            full_df = full_df.append(game_df, sort = False)

full_df = full_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (full_df.head(30).to_string())
                Player MIN    FG  3PT   FT OREB DREB REB AST STL BLK TO PF PTS  Team Home_Away Starter_Bench Pos      Date
0             H. Drame  22   2-7  0-2  0-0    1    1   2   0   0   1  1  4   4   SPU      Away       Starter   F  01/01/21
1             F. Drame  20   2-3  0-1  0-0    1    5   6   0   3   1  1  4   4   SPU      Away       Starter   F  01/01/21
2               M. Lee  24  2-11  0-4  1-2    1    2   3   0   0   0  3  0   5   SPU      Away       Starter   G  01/01/21
3             D. Banks  26  4-12  1-6  2-4    0    5   5   6   1   0  1  1  11   SPU      Away       Starter   G  01/01/21
4             D. Edert  32  6-10  2-4  1-2    0    4   4   0   2   0  1  2  15   SPU      Away       Starter   G  01/01/21
5           O. Diahame   1   0-1  0-0  0-0    0    0   0   0   0   0  0  0   0   SPU      Away         Bench   F  01/01/21
6             K. Ndefo  23  7-10  0-0  3-3    1    6   7   2   1   5  1  4  17   SPU      Away         Bench   F  01/01/21
7            B. Diallo  14   0-2  0-0  0-0    1    1   2   0   0   0  0  0   0   SPU      Away         Bench   G  01/01/21
8             T. Brake  24   1-2  0-1  0-0    0    0   0   1   0   0  0  1   2   SPU      Away         Bench   G  01/01/21
9           M. Silvera   6   0-0  0-0  0-0    0    1   1   1   0   0  1  0   0   SPU      Away         Bench   G  01/01/21
10            N. Kamba   8   0-1  0-0  0-0    0    0   0   0   0   0  2  0   0   SPU      Away         Bench   G  01/01/21
11            J. Fritz  38   5-9  0-0  4-5    2    8  10   4   1   3  1  3  14   CAN      Home       Starter   F  01/01/21
12            J. White  17   4-7  1-2  0-0    1    4   5   2   0   0  5  2   9   CAN      Home       Starter   F  01/01/21
13           A. Fofana  20   1-7  1-4  1-2    0    1   1   1   0   0  1  2   4   CAN      Home       Starter   G  01/01/21
14          A. Harried  23  3-10  1-4  0-1    2    5   7   1   1   1  0  1   7   CAN      Home       Starter   G  01/01/21
15        J. Henderson  37   3-8  3-5  5-6    0    1   1   2   0   0  1  1  14   CAN      Home       Starter   G  01/01/21
16      G. Maslennikov   2   0-2  0-1  0-0    0    0   0   0   0   0  1  1   0   CAN      Home         Bench   F  01/01/21
17            M. Green  18   3-4  0-0  2-2    1    4   5   2   1   0  2  1   8   CAN      Home         Bench   F  01/01/21
18          S. Hitchon   3   0-0  0-0  0-0    0    0   0   1   0   0  0  0   0   CAN      Home         Bench   F  01/01/21
19       S. Uijtendaal  20   2-4  1-2  0-0    0    0   0   0   1   0  0  2   5   CAN      Home         Bench   G  01/01/21
20          M. Brandon  19   4-5  1-2  0-0    0    3   3   2   2   0  2  1   9   CAN      Home         Bench   G  01/01/21
21           A. Ahemed   3   0-0  0-0  0-0    0    1   1   1   0   0  0  1   0   CAN      Home         Bench   G  01/01/21
22           K. Nwandu  34  5-13  1-3  0-1    1    3   4   3   1   0  3  1  11  NIAG      Away       Starter   F  01/01/21
23      G. Kuakumensah  23   1-2  1-2  1-2    0    2   2   1   0   0  1  1   4  NIAG      Away       Starter   F  01/01/21
24         N. Kratholm  18   4-7  0-0  3-5    2    2   4   1   0   0  0  2  11  NIAG      Away       Starter   F  01/01/21
25          M. Hammond  33  7-14  3-6  0-0    0    4   4   1   1   0  2  2  17  NIAG      Away       Starter   G  01/01/21
26          J. Roberts  28   2-6  2-6  2-2    0    2   2   3   1   0  2  3   8  NIAG      Away       Starter   G  01/01/21
27          J. Cintron  14   0-2  0-0  0-0    1    3   4   0   0   1  2  1   0  NIAG      Away         Bench   F  01/01/21
28  DonaldN. MacDonald   9   0-1  0-1  0-0    0    3   3   0   0   0  0  0   0  NIAG      Away         Bench   G  01/01/21
29          R. Solomon  25  4-11  0-2  2-2    1    3   4   0   3   0  0  1  10  NIAG      Away         Bench   G  01/01/21
```

Comment: That is awesome.  Thank you.  I am going to continue attempting to use sports reference for now just because I've spent so much time with it already, but I didn't even realize ESPN offered their own API and will keep that in mind for the future.  I do hope to continue this process for all the major sports.  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh ya ya! Just another option. I’ll take a look at the csv now to see if I can find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use that library. Just go with `requests`, `beautifulsoup`, and `pandas`. The library likely uses those under the hood. But this should work for you at the moment. We may need to add a few things (like a delay/sleep) when you get blocked for too many request in a short period of time, which I'm suspecting is what's causing you the problem, but this will get you going. See what it gets you and we can adjust it.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

season_df = pd.read_csv('C:/test/ncaab.csv')
links_list = season_df['BoxscoreIndex'].to_list()
delay = 30


def parse_tables(idx,basic_tables,advanced_tables):    
    try:
        basic = basic_tables[idx]
        advanced = advanced_tables[idx]
        team = basic.find('caption').text.split('(')[0].strip()
        team = team.split('Table')[0].strip()
        
        df_basic = pd.read_html(str(basic), header=1)[0]
        df_basic = df_basic[df_basic['Starters'] == 'School Totals']
        df_basic = df_basic.reset_index(drop=True)
        
        df_advanced = pd.read_html(str(advanced), header=1)[0]
        df_advanced = df_advanced[df_advanced['Starters'] == 'School Totals']
        df_advanced = df_advanced.reset_index(drop=True)
        
        drop_cols = []
        for col in df_basic.columns:
            if col in df_advanced.columns:
                drop_cols.append(col)
                
        df = df_basic.drop(['Starters'], axis=1).join(df_advanced.drop(drop_cols, axis=1))
        df['Team'] = team
        return df
    except:
        return None


def get_html(box_link):
    url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/boxscores/%s.html' %box_link
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        return soup, True
    else:
        return None, False
    


visited_links = []
errors_list = []
box_df = pd.DataFrame()
for box_link in tqdm(links_list):
    resp_success = False

    # This will skip odd rows
    if box_link in visited_links:
        continue
    
    while resp_success == False:
        soup, resp_success = get_html(box_link)
        if resp_success == False:
            print ('Will retry in %s seconds.' %delay)
            time.sleep(delay)
            
    basic_tables = soup.find_all('table', {'id': re.compile('.*box-score-basic.*')})
    advanced_tables = soup.find_all('table', {'id': re.compile('.*box-score-advanced.*')})
    
    if len(basic_tables) < 2:
        errors_list.append(box_link)
    
    for idx in range(0, len(basic_tables)):
        df = parse_tables(idx,basic_tables,advanced_tables)
        box_df = box_df.append(df, sort=False)
        
    visited_links.append(box_link)
 
        
box_df = box_df.reset_index(drop = True)
if len(errors_list) > 0:
    print('\n')
    print ('You may want to investigate the following.')
    for each in errors_list:
        print('Error with: %s' %each)
```

Comment: You've already been a huge help, so feel free to move on to the next helpless sap at any point, but I'm gonna keep asking questions until you get sick of me.  The code you provided works great with a couple of exceptions.  #1.  This generates a database with all the basic stats for each player associated with a given game.  The code I was writing is for team stats and I was looking for the more advanced stats provided in the box links for each game.  #2 Assuming I can figure out how to rewrite this code for team stats instead of player stats, I am a little lost as far as where to specify a

Comment: date range.  The reason I need team stats for each specific game is in the next step I am running an LGBM model to determine how important each stat was in determining the final score of the game.

Comment: By the way, I attempted to delete all duplicate box score links from my csv and run the code again and I got the index error at 3409 iterations now.  Maybe I will attempt to add the delay/sleep feature you mentioned and see if it works

Comment: Ok. Well a few things. 1) you could aggregate the player stats to get the team stats, but if you want team stats, we can get those. Was it the basic stats, or advanced? Or both? 2) ya I suspect it’s blocking you. Ya we’ll put in a delay, However let’s be smart, let’s only wait once the error occurs, and then continue. It’ll then run quicker. 3) once we do get it to work, it might be worth looking into running it in parallel, which I’ve never done, but would be interested in trying. 3) don’t worry about asking questions, it’s how we learn!

Comment: I didn’t add the date range here, as I thought you had that part figured out with just iterating through the csv file. But now that I know what your sort of doing, it’ll give me some direction.

Comment: Sounds great. I will email you the entire code so you can take a look.  I’ve only gotten to the point where it determines the different importance’s.  My ultimate plan is to take those importance factors and multiply them by their respective stats for each team to be able to predict the total expected points scored for each team for each game. I am only using a LGBM for right now, but I’ve already found lots of other possibly more accurate models to use as well.

Comment: I ran the code you provided and still got the error:IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-57a4c46171c8> in <module>
     78 
     79     for idx in [0,1]:
---> 80         df = parse_tables(idx)
     81         box_df = box_df.append(df, sort=False)
     82 

<ipython-input-3-57a4c46171c8> in parse_tables(idx)
 
     25 def parse_tables(idx):
---> 26     basic = basic_tables[idx]
     27     advanced = advanced_tables[idx]
     28     team = basic.find('caption').text.split('(')[0].strip()

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I will email the error message to you to make it more clear.  I am finishing a paper for school right now, but will attempt to mess around with it a bit later today and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Can you tell me which box_link it was. I have an idea of what the issue was.

Comment: It happened at iteration 6768 out of 14972.  The specific boxscore index for that game is: 2019-12-28-17-north-carolina-greensboro